# get_the_category - display only a single category for a post (not all categories)

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I am trying to display only one post category for a post, instead of them all. My current code is:

```
<?php
    $category = get_the_category($post_id);

    foreach($category as $cat){
        if ( $cat->cat_ID == '3'){
        
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><li><?php echo $cat->name ?></li></a>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

I know the following code is incorrect, but not sure how to to go about calling only 1 category.

```
if ( $cat->cat_ID == '3'){
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: By what criteria are you choosing which category to display? Just the first?

Comment: Why not just do `get_the_category($post_id)[0]` to get the first category, or just `break` your foreach after the first run?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to display a post's hierarchical categories (asked elsewhere but no replies), so thought I'd just display them individually. So it could be the 1st category, or the 3rd category, etc. I've been away from WordPress for many years, so feel like a beginner again, haha.